# How to put a text in particular position of an image?

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, nodes, includegraphics

I'm working with overleaf and trying to add texts in these red marked positions. For example, I want to add 4,5 and 6 respectively. I've tried with \put(0,0), but it always disables the \resizebox attribute and makes the image out of proportion, also the text doesn't get placed in the position at all. What changes can I make in the code mention below to add 4,5 and 6 in these three positions? Picture can be found in [this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJDcI.png).

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
    \resizebox{1\linewidth}{!}{%
    \includegraphics{picture.png}
    }
    \caption{Flowchart of Heuristic adjustment 1.}
    \label{fig:heuristic_1_FC}
\end{figure}
```

[image: 4,5,6 should be added respectively in the red marked positions]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! How the picture is drawn? If is by TikZ package, the simplest way is add desired text in image. Otherwise include image in TikZ node and find desired position with something like `[node distance = <height> and <width> of <node name>.south west]`

Comment: Why did you use resizebox on the includegraphics command? Why not simply use the width option of includegraphics?

Comment: @Zarko, thank you for the suggestion. Worked very nicely.

Comment: @leandriis, sorry I didn't know about the width option. I'm a newbie. I'll use it in future for sure. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look if it suits your requirement-- the red circles need to be removed-- a little bit of fine tuning may be required by varying the x,y coordinates-- the green color can be changed or made white as per your choice

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix, arrows.meta, positioning, 
 decorations,decorations.markings, math}
 
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[above right,
        inner sep=0
        ] 
        (image) at (0,0) {
                        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{yJDcI.png}
                            };
% Create scope with normalized axes
\begin{scope}[
x={($0.1*(image.south east)$)},
y={($0.1*(image.north west)$)}]

    
% Labels
\node[circle,fill=green] at (2.85,3.3){\scriptsize 4};

\node[circle,fill=green] at (6.35,3.3){\scriptsize 5};

\node[circle,fill=green] at (7.15,0.82){\scriptsize 6};

 \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked like a charm.